# Padronizar largura barras entre gráficos distintos ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Olá, gostaria de saber como posso padronizar a largura das minhas barras do `ggplot2` entre gráficos distintos. Gostaria de deixar as barras de todos gráficos na mesma largura. Por exemplo, tenho esses dois gráficos com barras de larguras diferentes, gostaria de deixar as barras dos dois gráficos com a mesma largura.

Para tentar resolver essa questão eu estava tentando colocar o argumento de largura, `width` igual em todos os gráficos, entretanto, não resolveu. Obrigada

Código do gráfico 1:

```
ebov_data <- data.frame(
  BioProject_acession_number=c("PRJNA352396", "PRJNA352396"),
  status=c("control", "patient"), 
  samples=c(16, 158))

ggplot(ebov_data, aes(x=BioProject_acession_number, y = samples, fill = status)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.8) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#00BFC4", "#F8766D")) +
  ggtitle("Ebola study") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(y = "number of samples", x = "BioProject's acession number") +
  geom_text(aes(label=samples), position=position_dodge(width=0.8), vjust=-0.5)
```

Código do gráfico 2:

```
dengue_data <- data.frame(
GEO_acession_number=c("GSE51808","GSE51808", "GSE28991", "GSE28991", "GSE28988", "GSE28988", "GSE28405", "GSE28405", "GSE25001", "GSE25001", "GSE13052", "GSE13052", "GSE116672", "GSE116672"),
status=c("control", "patient", "control", "patient", "control", "patient", "control", "patient", "control", "patient", "control", "patient", "control", "patient"), 
samples=c(28, 28, 11, 22, 96, 210, 31, 62, 34, 175, 12, 18, 4, 6))  

  ggplot(dengue_data, aes(x=GEO_acession_number, y = samples, fill = status)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.8) +
       scale_fill_manual(values=c("#00BFC4", "#F8766D")) +
       ggtitle("Dengue studies") +
       theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
       labs(y = "number of samples", x = "GEO's acession number") +
       geom_text(aes(label=samples), position=position_dodge(width=0.8), vjust=-0.5)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oi, Vanessa. O que já tentou fazer?

Comment: Tentei colocar o argumento width com valor igual para todos gráficos, porém, não resolveu

Comment: Acho legal editar sua pergunta e colocar esta tentativa que fez lá também, mostrando código também (se for o caso). O SO valoriza muito perguntas que o autor já tentou alguma coisa e não resolveu, assim tem menos chances da pergunta ser fechada... além de que ajuda as pessoas a entenderem o que tentou fazer e descartar como possível resposta.

Comment: De onde vêm os dados do segundo gráfico? Só temos os dados e código do primeiro.

Answer (score 1):

**Nota:** A seguinte solução talvez não seja o que se pede.

Para garantir de uma forma automática que as barras são da mesma largura, vou juntar os dois conjuntos de dados criando uma nova coluna, `Data`, que diz qual o conjunto de dados, `"Dengue"` ou `"Ebola"`, e traçar os gráficos em duas facetas.

Para isso, vou usar o pacote `dplyr`.

Em primeiro lugar, ver qual o conjunto de dados final (temporário), que vai ser passado ao `ggplot`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ebov_data %>%
  mutate(Data = "Ebola") %>%
  rename(Acession_number = ends_with("acession_number")) %>%
  bind_rows(dengue_data %>%
              mutate(Data = "Dengue") %>%
              rename(Acession_number = ends_with("acession_number")))
#   Acession_number  status samples   Data
#1      PRJNA352396 control      16  Ebola
#2      PRJNA352396 patient     158  Ebola
#3         GSE51808 control      28 Dengue
#4         GSE51808 patient      28 Dengue
#5         GSE28991 control      11 Dengue
#6         GSE28991 patient      22 Dengue
#7         GSE28988 control      96 Dengue
#8         GSE28988 patient     210 Dengue
#9         GSE28405 control      31 Dengue
#10        GSE28405 patient      62 Dengue
#11        GSE25001 control      34 Dengue
#12        GSE25001 patient     175 Dengue
#13        GSE13052 control      12 Dengue
#14        GSE13052 patient      18 Dengue
#15       GSE116672 control       4 Dengue
#16       GSE116672 patient       6 Dengue
```

> Warning messages:
>   1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
>   2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
>     binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
>   3: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
>     binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector

Agora é só passar isto com mais um *pipe* `%>%` ao `ggplot`, que tem algumas alterações. O truque está nos argumentos `scales` e `space` de `facet_grid`. Estes argumentos modificam as larguras das facetas e portanto das barras.

```
ebov_data %>%
  mutate(Data = "Ebola") %>%
  rename(Acession_number = ends_with("acession_number")) %>%
  bind_rows(dengue_data %>%
              mutate(Data = "Dengue") %>%
              rename(Acession_number = ends_with("acession_number"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Acession_number, y = samples, fill = status)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=samples),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            vjust=-0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#00BFC4", "#F8766D")) +
  ggtitle("Dengue and Ebola Studies") +
  labs(y = "number of samples", x = "Acession Number") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 10),
        strip.background = element_blank()) +
  facet_grid(~ Data, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]